# How can I show an image from raw pixel data in GTK using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, graphics, gtk

I would like to create an image in Haskell using the Rasterific library and then display that image in a GTK window;  the Rasterific library lets me generate an RBGA-formatted 32-bit pixel depth image, but I am having trouble figuring out how I can take this raw image and display it in a window or drawarea or whatever in GTK.

(I've spent a lot of time looking through the documentation, but I've been having a hard time seeing how to fit the parts together, especially since the Haskell documentation is often non-existent and at some point the cairo library gets involved in a way that's not entirely clear to me.)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a package called [AC-EasyRaster-GTK](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AC-EasyRaster-GTK) for this exact purpose.

It's a wrapper around gtk2hs. That library gives all the necessary parts, but it's not actually all that easy to figure out. So I wrote a library so I wouldn't have to keep looking this stuff up!

`ib_new` gives you a new image buffer, `ib_write_pixel` lets you write a pixel, and `ib_display` will start the GTK event loop, display the bitmap in a window, and block the calling thread until the user clicks close. Sadly, there's no easy way to chuck an entire array at GTK. (It demands a particular pixel order, which varies by platform...)

Comment: Ugh, I don't really want the overhead of drawing each pixel individually, but thanks!

Comment: The `ib_write_pixel` function is only doing manipulations on a Haskell array. It's not like it actually makes a GTK call per pixel. (That really *is* slow! I've tried it...)

Comment: As well, you could try browsing the source code of the module to see what GTK functions it's actually using, and hence how the pieces "fit together".

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I'm not finding it either. You can iterate over all the pixels in the original image using something like `forM_ (range ((0,0),(w,h)))` and draw them onto a Cairo drawing using something like this: (The Cairo calls are correct but I'm just guessing about the Rasterific functions)

```
drawPixel color x y = do
  setSourceRGBA (red color) (green color) (blue color) (alpha color)
  rectangle x y 1 1
  paint
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am hoping to avoid drawing the pixels individually.